# Apache + Passenger + Rails and Client certificates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, passenger

I'm trying to authenticate API users with X.509 certificates and I got it almost together. The only problem is how to get cert information (especially **PEM cert data**) from Apache to Rails.

This ENV variable contain what I need:

```
ENV['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']
```

But that seems to be fixed to the **first request** after spawning Passenger process and not reset for every request.

Answers to [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8369776) by the author of Passenger seems to confirm that ENV variables are freezed and not reset for every request.

**Is there any way to get correct certificate data from Apache to Rails?**

I think I could use some magic to create a custom header, but that is not quite secure as malicious client could set that too.

Comment: Would the `PEM cert data` change with every client request? I think it would remain the same unless changed on the server.

Comment: I'm talking about Client certificates, which identify the client - i.e by definition MUST change with every different client. Currently Rails sees all clients as the **first** one to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until any other option presents itself, I still opted for the header trick:

Ensure `mod_headers` is loaded and then in your virtual host conf:

```
# Ensure that client can not pass certificate header
RequestHeader unset X-Api-Client-Cert
# Require client cert for API
<Location /api>
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData
    # Now export CertData via header
    RequestHeader set X-Api-Client-Cert "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
</Location>
```

And then, in Rails code use:

```
cert_data = request.headers['X-Api-Client-Cert']
```

It does not matter what to use as header name in place of `X-Api-Client-Cert`. Admittedly [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not real security, but I chose to use custom header name just to minimise probability of this header clashing with anything a real client would send without intent.

Comment: I don't think that there is any obscurity issue here: you remove any X-Api-Client-Cert that some attacker might have inserted, so I think you are good.